# What is the best way to customize a widget’s JS script?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, widget

I have a plugin that serves it’s own widget.  I need to make a slight change to a few of the events in the widget’s `js` file.  Since I don’t want to edit the `widget.js` file directly, my understanding is that I need to deregister the script via my theme’s `functions.php` file and then register a customized version that lives in my theme’s directory.  Upon inspection of the script in the `widget.php` file, this is what I am seeing:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'berocket_aapf_widget-script', plugins_url( '../js/widget.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), BeRocket_AJAX_filters_version );
 }
```

So over in my theme’s `functions.php` file I have attempted the following to dequeue this script:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'berocket_aapf_widget-script' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'berocket_aapf_widget-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 99999999 );
```

This unfortunately is not doing the trick.  Am I approaching this in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend abandoning the plugin's own JS file. I know you're copying the data with it, but still.

That being said, your code has some weak points. You need to dequeue and then deregister a script/style. And you should try dequeing the script in the wp_enqueue_scripts hook as wp_print_scripts is executed after the wp_enqueu_scripts.

Ref: [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Other than the above points, you're doing it right.

Edit 1:
I am not suggesting to edit the plugin's original JS file but to hook/bind your custom JS and make it work with the original file in place.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I edit the plugin's widget JS file?  I am just concerned that edits may be overwritten when updating the plugin.

Comment: @Presto No, I am suggesting to bind/hook your custom JS to work with the original code. If you could send your site link and the JS you want to add, maybe I can help even more.

Comment: I am working locally at the moment.  Do you have a reference on hooking into exisiting JS?

Comment: @presto Please pardon my vocabulary but if you're confused between the word HOOK and WP's hooks. By hooking to JS, I mean bind to it or make it work with the original JS.

Comment: can you send a simple example of how to bind to original JS?

Comment: I have created a `custom.js` file in my theme which loads after the widget's JS file.  I then triggered an event which fires on the same event after the widget's JS event.  In this area I have a script which does what I need.  Is this the method that you are suggesting?

Comment: @Presto of course. And sorry for the communication barriers.